# Solve system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, education

I wrote the following code:

```
Solve[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}, {x}]
```

Mathematica does not solve it. How can I get the result x=1/5?

Thank you so much for your willingness.

Comment: what if VIN = 0? or VOUT=0?

Comment: Hello @Nasser, maybe Mathematica assumes VIN and VOUT as non zero constant by default....but this must to be verify.

Comment: @Nasser - "Solve gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed. Other solutions that are only conditionally valid are expressed as ConditionalExpression objects."

Comment: Another hack: `Solve[Eliminate[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}, {VOUT}], {x}]` giving `{{x -> 1/5}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Solve[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}, {x, VOUT}]
(*{{x -> 1/5, VOUT -> 5 VIN}}*)
```

Comment: Hello @UlrichNeumann, your solution is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: In recent versions, you can also just use `Solve[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}]`

Comment: ... also `Solve[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}, {x}, MaxExtraConditions -> 1]`

Comment: Or `Solve[{x == VIN/VOUT, VOUT == 5 VIN}, x, {VOUT}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon is that option documented? I thought third argument was only *domain*.

Comment: @rhermans - This syntax was documented in earlier versions but the documentation stopped mentioning it. However, it appears to be kept for backward compatibility. The variables to be eliminated must be in list brackets, e.g., `{VOUT}`. If you were to enter just `VOUT` then Mma would first try to interpreted it as a domain resulting in the warning: `Solve::bdomv: Warning: VOUT is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate.` and then give the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[
 {
  x == VIN/VOUT,
  VOUT == 5 VIN
  }, {x}
 ]
(* VIN == VOUT/5 && x == 1/5 && VOUT != 0 *)

Solve@Reduce[
  {
   x == VIN/VOUT,
   VOUT == 5 VIN
   }, {x}
  ]
(* {{VOUT -> 5 VIN, x -> 1/5}} *)
```